# Custom Cell, only last cell gets [layoutSubviews]?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uitableview

I'm creating a Settings View for my app, and in that view is a UITableView. I'm creating custom cells to meet my needs, but I'm having issues - only the last cell is getting `[layoutSubviews]`. Am I doing something wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //int type = (indexPath.row == 0?1:0);
    //if(indexPath.row == 6) type = 2;

    NSLog(@"row %i created", indexPath.row);
    TableCell *cell = [[TableCell alloc] initWithType:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test cell";

    return cell;
}
```

And in my custom cell:

```
@implementation TableCell

UIImageView *shadowView;
int row;

- (id) initWithType:(int)type {
    row = type;

    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    UIImage *shadowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CellShadow"];
    shadowImage = [shadowImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(14, 14, 14, 14)];

    shadowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:shadowImage];

    [self.contentView addSubview:shadowView];
    //[self.contentView sendSubviewToBack:shadowView];

    NSLog(@"agreed, row %i created", row);

    [self layoutSubviews];

    return self;
}

- (void) layoutSubviews {
    NSLog(@"row: %i", row);

    [super layoutSubviews];

    shadowView.frame = CGRectMake(
        0, 0,
        self.contentView.frame.size.width,
        self.contentView.frame.size.height
    );
}

@end
```

Continuously, only the last cell #6, is reported when I rotate, or when layoutSubviews should be called. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was of my own poor code. Using `cell.backgroundView` helped a lot here.

Answer (score 3):

Do not call `layoutSubviews` directly.  Use `[self setNeedsLayout]` or `[self layoutIfNeeded]`.  But do not call these at all in the cell's init method.

Also, do not call [[TableCell alloc] initWithType:indexPath.row]; directly, either.  Instead, use...

`- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Once you've built that cell, you can tell it it's row, but be aware that the cells get recycled as the table scrolls, so you must update that value on every call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

The cells ought to get layout again (without you making any calls direct or indirect) when the table view is resized.

See the [tableview doc here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But even with [self setNeedsLayout] and not the direct call to layoutSubviews, only the last row gets layoutSubviews when the view is rotated.

Comment: I should have read your code more carefully.  (the layout subviews mistake overtook my attention.  those should definitely be removed).  I've edited the answer.  First get the cells built properly, the layout should work fine.  If not, try tableView reloadData upon rotation, but you shouldn't need it.

Comment: I'm not using reusable cells, since this will be a Settings View, and it's a small number of cells. And it doesn't seem to work regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You should never call `layoutSubviews` directly, it will be called automatically by iOS once the cell is ready to display. You should also deque the cell as @danh is recommending. If you're not very comfortable with all this, then I'd really recommend you have a look at the free Sensible TableView framework, which automates creating these kind of settings views (I create mine in a couple of lines, really).

Answer (score 0):

Never Call layoutSubviews by yourself. It will be called when ever frames of subview in cell are changed. Even if just change the text of labels in your custom cell wont call layoutSubviews. Ue the deque of cells for reusing for better performance. As it wont allocate cell every time. And in you code looks like has lot of memory issues since cell allocated wont be released and new cell is created.

Comment: Yes, I've made a lot of changes since that allow for allocation and reuse, and solved the problem. Thank you for the notes!